# django: valueerror on optional field

Tags: django

This is my first django project, I'm not sure why I'm getting an error 'The 'image2' attribute has no file associated with it.' when those fields are optional. How can I fix this?

model

```
class LinksContent(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default= True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    somecontent = HTMLField(blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    links = (
    ('faculties', 'faculties'),
    ('admission', 'admission'),
    ('resources', 'resources'),
    ('staff', 'staff'),
    ('research', 'research'),
    )
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to = 'files/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=13, choices=links)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
```

html>

```
{% if content %}
    {% for item in content %}
        <div class="theHeader">
            <img class = 'header-img' src = "{{ item.image.url }}">
            <div class = 'author-info'>
                <img class = 'admin-img' src = "{{ item.author.image.url}}">
                <p>&nbsp;{{ item.author}} &nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;{{ item.publish_date | naturaltime}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
            <p>{{ item.somecontent | safe }}</p>
            <div class = 'data'>
                <img class = 'images' src = "{{ item.image2.url }}">
                <img class = 'images' src = "{{ item.image3.url }}">
                <img class = 'images' src = "{{ item.image4.url }}">
            </div>
            <div class = 'data'>
                <p><a class = 'link' href = "{{ link.file1.url }}">Download Link</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div>
        <p>No data available</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blank=True` means that your fields are optional during the the *Form* submission, if you want the field to optional in your *Model* during its creation you need to add `null=True` to the field in your **Model** like this:

```
image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: that is good to know. I solve my problem with if statements for each field. Thank you for the help!